# SAS_How to call a cumulative concat in array

Tags: sas, regression, logistic-regression

I encounter a need to perform the following action but I am not sure how to achieve this.

I have a table with variables I need to perform regression and the table looks like

```
Colummn name | Y | X1 | X2 | X3 | ....| X10 |

Row 1 __________ | - | ---  | ---  | ---  | ....| ---   |

Row 2 __________       | - | ---  | ---  | ---  | ....| ---   |
```

I want to run 10 regressions and compare the adjusted R Squared of each model, with the regression code being:

```
proc reg data = table outest = out_table;
model modelN /adjrsq;
run;quit;
```

In the 10 models, the Y variable remains unchanged, with the X variable to increase by 1 each time:

Model1: Y = X1;

Model2: Y = X1 +X2

Model3: Y = X1+ X2 +X3

.....

Model10: Y = X1+X2+X3+....+X10

I want to write a
`DO i = 1 to 10`
to perform the task for simplicity and convenience. The final output could be 10 out_tables from the PROC REG codes. However, I don't know how to refer to the dependent variable in the loop. Could anybody help with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought, I wonder if you could do it in one PROC GLMSELECT step with forward selection, something like /selection= forward slentry=1 .  Unfortunately I don't see a way to force the order that variables are added. PROC LOGISTIC has a sequential option for forward selection, but I don't see it for GLMSELECT or REG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your x variables are named x1, x2, x3, etc., you can use the `-` shortcut to select them in order.

```
%macro model(n);
    %do i = 1 %to &n;
        model&i: model y=x1-x&i /adjrsq;
    %end;
%mend;

proc reg data=have outest=out_table;
    %model(10);
run;
```

If the variables are not sequentially named, you'll have to do a little extra prep code. In this case, we'll read all the input variables from a pipe-separated list and use `--` instead. `--` selects all columns between two columns that you specify, including those two columns. e.g. `foo--bar` would select `foo`, `bar`, and all variables in-between `foo` and `bar`.

```
/* Create a pipe-separated list of all input variables, making sure to
   exclude the dependent variable */
proc sql noprint;
    select name
    into :varlist separated by '|'
    from dictionary.columns
    where    memname = 'HAVE' 
         AND libname = 'WORK'
         AND name NE 'Y'
    order by varnum
    ;
quit;

%macro model(n);
    %do i = 1 %to &n;
        model&i: model y=%scan(&varlist, 1, |)--%scan(&varlist, &i, |) /adjrsq;
    %end;
%mend;

proc reg data=have outest=out_table;
    %model(10);
run;
```

Comment: Dear Stu, thanks so much for your help! I have successfully implement the procedure following your advice. All the best